# Integration options for NextJS with Azure B2C Open ID Connect

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

We have a requirement to integrate NextJS app with Azure B2C using Authorization Code Flow with PKCE.

While researching I came across to options below:

1. BFF (Backend for Front End)  - Uses  proper API hosted on same
   subdomain as FE site so that it can issue token.
   https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/
2. Use NextJS integrating with Azure B2C using SSR API routes (of NextJS):

   https://www.devgould.com/jwt-authentication-with-nextjs-bff-backend-for-frontend/
3. Use NextAuth.JS
   https://benjaminwfox.com/blog/tech/how-to-configure-azure-b2c-with-nextjs
4. Use Microsoft MSAL
   https://medium.com/ascentic-technology/authentication-with-msal-js-2fe281098038

Keen to get expert advise on which one of the approach above is secured, maintainable and speed to market.